Discrepancy in recursive definition of maximum
I'm following along some lecture notes here: https://tylerarant.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/114c_w23_notes_nr.pdf
Context:
We are dealing with $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ with truncated subtraction.
For $x, y$, we have that $x/2 := \mu y[x \dot− (2 · y) = 0]$
and
$|x - y| := (x \dot− y) + (y \dot− x)$
Question:
On page 17, the notes define $\max(x, y) = \frac{x + y}{2} + \frac{|x - y|}{2}$
However, I noted that due to the division definition, we will always have that for
$x = 2n + 1$ and $y = 2m$
the result is
$\max(x, y) = n + m + 2 + |n - m|$
which notably leads to
$\max(0, 1) = 2$.
Did I make a mistake, or are the notes correct?

Can you expand on the calculation of $\frac12$ from the definition?

Lemma 2.6 defines $x/2$ (where $x\in\mathbb N$) to be the smallest $y\in\mathbb N$ such that $x-2y\leq 0.$ So $1/2=1.$ Therefore,
$$
\min(0,1):=\frac{0+1}{2}+\frac{|0-1|}{2} = \frac12 + \frac12 = 1+1 = 2.
$$
However, if you modify the definition to be
$$\max(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)+|x-y|}{2}$$
then you get
$$
\max(0,1) = \frac{(0+1)+|0-1|}{2} = \frac{1+1}{2}= \frac22 = 1.
$$

Thank you! That was what I thought as well.
